how to ensure that the kubelet read-only-port is secured
During a recent penetration test of our Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster, it was identified that Kubelet's read-only API is exposed. This poses a security risk as unauthenticated access to the read-only API can reveal potentially sensitive information about the cluster. We need to know if disabling this read-only API is possible in AKS and how it can be done.
Here's what we've done thus far, on both the master and worker nodes, with no results.
launched a debug pod in AKS
opened /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service
added --read-only-port=0 under ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/kubelet as an argument
save and exit
opened /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig
added readOnlyPort: 0
save and exit
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart kubelet
How we tested
kubectl proxy
curl http://127.0.0.1:8001
Even after all the config changes above the curl command returned all the information that it should not.
We have a retest coming up and need to resolve this ASAP.
Kindly assist
Thank you

If anyone has any insights or tips, that would be awesome
